# Does apt care if I put the -f flag before or after the command?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

When I get a dependency conflict, `install -f` should correct problems.

What is the difference between `apt-get install -f` 
and `apt-get -f install`?

Answer (score 2):

Both `apt-get install -f` and `apt-get -f install` mean the same.

From `man apt-get`:

```
   -f, --fix-broken
       Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This
       option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT
       to deduce a likely solution. If packages are specified, these have to
       completely correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary when
       running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken package
       dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency
       structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually
       means using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending
       packages). Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
       situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

Comment: @OerHeks If this post answered your question, please mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the order in which you provide those options to apt-get really matters. They mean the same thing.

`sudo apt-get -y install` is equivalent to `sudo apt-get install -y`